# How to perform column bind between two datasets in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I have two data sets containing the same number of rows.
I want to perform column bind on the two datasets to create a third dataset.
How can we perform this in SAS?

This can be done in R using cbind(), is there an equivalent in SAS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple merge should work in SAS. If you leave out the `by` statement then it will merge on row number.  First check the setting of the `mergenoby` option to make sure it isn't set to error.

```
proc options option=mergenoby;
run;
```

If it is set to error then run the following statement before the merge.

```
option mergenoby=nowarn;
```

Otherwise this merge statement will join the 2 datasets by row number.

```
data ds1;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 2 3
6 7 8
11 12 13
;
run;

data ds2;
input d e;
datalines;
4 5
9 10
14 15
;
run;

data ds3;
merge ds1 ds2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||` function

example :

```
proc iml;
x1=j(5,1,1);
x2=j(5,1,2);
data1=x1||x2;
x1=j(5,1,3);
x2=j(5,1,4);
data2=x1||x2;
data=data1||data2;
print data;
run;
quit;
```

results :

```
   data 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: and you can use (//) for rbind

Comment: Why not?`proc iml;
x1=j(5,1,1);
x2=j(5,1,2);
x3=j(5,1,3);
x4=j(5,1,4);
data=x1||x2||x3||x4;
print data;
run;
quit;`

Answer (score 1):

Below code will also produce column bind operation on input data sets and produce output data set. Output dataset 'out' will contain four variables a,b,c and d and 3 observations.

```
data ds1;
 input a b;
 datalines;
10 20
50 60
70 90
;
run;

data ds2;
input c d;
datalines;
11 22
55 77
88 99
;
run;

data out; /* Third data step */
 set ds1;
 set ds2;
run;
```

Output dataset out will look like:

```
a   b  c  d
10 20 11 22
50 60 55 77
70 90 88 99
```

Working: For every loop of the third data step, each observation from two input datasets ds1 and ds2 will be fetched into PDV and output is written into output dataset.

This step will work very good if both input datasets have same number of rows. If number of rows in any one of the input dataset is less then data step will terminate whenever end of data occurs for that dataset and output dataset will have number of observations equal to input dataset with less number of observations. i.e. if ds1 and ds2 contains 10 and 5 observations each, then output dataset out will contain only 5 observations.